# How to disable PHP Laravel Form conditionally?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm complete new to php lavarel, i'm using a conditon that checks if the user is logged, if the user is not logged, the forms should be disabled for the guest user.

The thing is i have searched i have found nothing useful to this.
i have tried something like this:

```
 {!! Form::text('series_folio', $series_folio, array('class'=>"form-control", 'id'=>"series_folio", 'placeholder'=>"Serie y/o Folio de la factura",'disabled'=>@if($islogged) "disabled" @endif)) !!}
```

and this:

```
 {!! Form::text('series_folio', $series_folio, array('class'=>"form-control", 'id'=>"series_folio", 'placeholder'=>"Serie y/o Folio de la factura",'disabled'=>{{@if($islogged) "disabled" @endif}})) !!}
```

Is possible to do this? How i can do it correctly?

**Additional info:**

I read the answer from the 'this question is a duplicate', That doesn't anser my question, because i don't want to disable the whole form, just a few fields.

Comment: What do you want to disable? The whole form or a field in the form?

Comment: @SteveNosse just the field, some other fields are avaiable for guests too.